# Namespace: System.Windows.Media.Imaging trying to use it in my c# class

Tags: c#

Namespace:  System.Windows.Media.Imaging

I am trying to use this a calss from this namespace but when I try to add it using 'using' in my directives I do not see System.Windows and the namepace. How to add it to my project so I can use BitmapImage class from it.

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: Do you have it in your references?

Comment: You need to add *two* assemblies to keep the compiler happy about you trying to use this WPF class. Project + Properties, Add Reference and add both PresentationCore and WindowsBase.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace is part of PresentationCore.dll (if you are using Visual Studio 2008 then the WPF application template will automatically add this reference). Note that this namespace is not a direct wrapping of the WIC library, although a large proportion of the more common uses are still available and it is relatively obvious how these map to the WIC versions.

Answer (score 0):

Right click "**References**" in the **Solution Explorer**, select **Add Reference**. in the popup click the **Brows**e tab. Look for the specific file you want to reference. Now make sure you have the declaration at the top of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add "PresentationCore.dll" to your project references described below by haakon319